# Magento products are not showing in admin panel

Tags: magento, panel, admin, product

I installed price count down extension, products are showing in admin panel when i click the product it showing me a blank page. I uninstalled the extension still the problem persists. Please any suggestions .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please remove module xml file from modules folder and remove cache and try to try compilation process again its enable